# Spring JPA sequence generator initial value is not working

Tags: spring, postgresql

I have one entity that already have records in database (20 records).
My primary key column is already defined as `SERIAL` in a **postgres** database.
My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo", schema = "public")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FooEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="foo_seq", sequenceName = "foo_seq", initialValue = 20, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "foo_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
}
```

I run a query that returns all existing sequences in database and i find the "foo_seq".
In my service, when i try to call my repository to save the data, its returned this error:

```
  FooEntity fooEntity = FooEntity.builder()
      .id(null)
      .build();
FooEntity savedEntity = fooRepository.save(fooEntity);
```

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key
> value violates unique constraint "foo_pkey"   Detail: Key (id)=(5)
> already exists.

Seems that spring is not using the value defined in `initialValue` (should try to save with id 20, but instead, is using your own increment starting with 1). When i call this method again, the increment is added, but not starting with 20.

I'm missing something? Should i have alter this sequence in postgres to start with id 20?

Comment: check this query SELECT last_value FROM foo_seq;

Comment: Does your sequence start from 1 in the database?

Comment: my start value is 1, but i already have records in my table. I should alter my sequence to start with 20?

Comment: probably but i dont remember how srry